# Xamarin : Using ArrayAdapter in an Android Fragment

Tags: android, xamarin, fragment, spinner, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to use an ArrayAdapter to populate a Spinner view located in a Fragment as follows

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SalaryDefinition, container, false);

        spnBanks = view.FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner1);

        spnBanks.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(CONTEXT, Resource.Layout.SalaryDefinition, Sections);

        return view;
    }
```

The problem is that I can't find a context to pass to the ArrayAdapter constructor.

Any idea how do I solve this, or generally populate a Spinner view in a Fragment?

Comment: have u solved this problem???

Comment: nope, I had to avoid fragments all together to get over it.

Comment: whats the alternative you have taken??

Comment: Alternatives depends greatly on the context at which you are using fragments.

Answer (score 0):

`Fragment` has the `getActivity` method, which returns the Activity this fragment is currently associated with. Use that in place of `CONTEXT`.

Comment: I am using Xamarin, not java.

Comment: The basic concept does not change. You should have the possibility to access the activity the hosts the fragment

Comment: `fragment.Activity` gives the parent or holder activity of the `Fragment`. The difference is some of the `get` and `set`  methods of java are used as `property` in c# (in xamarin),though if i am not wrong, all the getters and setters in java can be used as `[access_specifier] [type] property_name {get; set;}` in C#.

Comment: you can use `this.Activity` in case of C# to get the `parent` or `holding` activity.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you should do in `OnCreateView` is to create your layout and return it.

Creating an adapter would be better in `OnActivityCreated` where you can access `this.Activity` to get the Activity that hosts the Fragment. The Activity can then be used as a Context.

Comment: what? no. The Fragment is attached after onAttach is called and this happens before OnCreateView

Comment: Yeah, my fault. Deleted it.

Comment: I have tried using this.Activity in both OnCreateView and OnActivityCreated events but it crashes the application!

Comment: It doesn't throw any exceptions, it just gives me "Unfotunately App1 has stopped!" message and closes the application.

Comment: Was there a resolution to this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a

> private Context context;

In your OnCreateView, do :

> context = container.Context;

And finally replace CONTEXT in your adapter by "context".

Answer (score 0):

After working through this the [following](http://davidyardy.com/archive/xamarin-listviews/) works just fine.  I have provided an example within methods OnCreateView and also OnActivityCreated

http://davidyardy.com/archive/xamarin-listviews/

Answer (score 0):

Use **this.Activity.BaseContext**

```
spnBanks.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this.Activity.BaseContext, Resource.Layout.SalaryDefinition, Sections);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Sisyphus I think I realized your problem :)
Because you inherited from the fragment, you are not able to use the usual method.
You will see a **...is not assignable to parameter to type "android.app.activity" ** error message.
You should use the following method:

```
spnBanks.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this.Activity,  Resource.Layout.SalaryDefinition, Sections);
```